# Как убрать неуязвимость после получения урона на сервере Minecraft Spigot 1.15.2

Tags: java, bukkit-api

Вот что-то да получилось но сервер выдает Plugin noHitCooldown v1.0 does not specify an api-version и не работает (кулдаун всё ещё есть)

**Main:**

```
package my.noHitCD.pulgin.noentityinvulnerabityplugin;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new EventsListener(), this);
    }
    
}
```

**EventListener:**

```
package my.noHitCD.pulgin.noentityinvulnerabityplugin;

import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageEvent;

public class EventsListener implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public void entityDamaged(EntityDamageEvent e) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
    }
}
```

**plugin.yml**

```
name: noHitCooldown
main: my.noHitCD.pulgin.noentityinvulnerabityplugin
api-version: 1.13
version: 1.0
author: [V0W4N]
```

каким методом можно обезвредить кд на урон?

Comment: Я не очень понял способ получения, неуязвимости, но как вариант, можно создать свой Bukkit Scheduler и проверять `isInvulnerable`.
Или вы пытаетесь на уровне ядра это исправить?

Comment: Хотя вы подключили JavaPlugin.... Метод `onEnable` определен в классе `JavaPlugin`, он переопределяется для того чтобы указать что нужно сделать, при включении вашего плагина.

Comment: @BigTows я пытался сделать что-то по гайдам но столкнулся с проблемой что я не знаю как и чем проверять состояние энтити после нанесения урона. Считай что кода тут толком и нет, ведь я писал наугад роясь в Entity.class баккита и нашёл разве что isInvulnerable и setInvulnerable, а на счёт onEnable я просто не знал что ещё можно туда вбить

Comment: Есть механизм [эвентов](https://spigotmc.ru/resources/bukkit-api-napisanie-plagina-ehventy-i-komandy.162/)  в API, есть эвент [EntityDamageEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/event/entity/EntityDamageEvent.html) попробуйте его использовать.

Comment: А у вас есть видео с воспроизведением бага? Может чем помогу.

Comment: Я имею ввиду что я хочу сделать так, чтобы энтити не ставали неуязвимыми на 0.5 секунд после получения любого вида урона (недосказал извиняюсь)

Comment: А после чего это происходит? Может сервер лагает?

Comment: это ванильная фича, во время того как мобы стают красными и урон ни проходит никакой (кроме падения), я хочу это отключить чтобы был смысл делать что-либо скорострельное (грубо говоря сменить значение неуязвимости после удара на 0)

Comment: Тогда пробуйте с эвентами поиграться

Comment: @BigTows проверьте пост, обновил и расписал до чего дошёл

Comment: Вам необходимо добавит в ваш [plugin.yml](https://github.com/ZendalMinecraft/RandomTeleport/blob/master/src/main/resources/plugin.yml) `api-version: 1.13`

Comment: @BigTows плюётся исключением  org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Cannot find main class 'my.noHitCD.pulgin.noentityinvulnerabityplugin' хотя я main сделал. Как мне сказать ему где мейн?

Comment: Добавьте ваш `plugin.yml` в вопрос

Comment: @BigTows добавил

Comment: В вашем случае main будет: `my.noHitCD.pulgin.noentityinvulnerabityplugin.Main` (забыли имя класса)